# Yii - Show Uploaded File from DetailView

Tags: php, yii

I've successfully uploaded a file (pdf), but I want to know how to show it when I click the link.
[image]

Here are my codes:
1. FileContoller.php

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model=new File;

    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(isset($_POST['File']))
    {
        $simpan=$model->nama_file=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'nama_file');
        if(empty($simpan)){
            $model->attributes=$_POST['File'];
            $model->save();
        }
        else{
        $model->attributes=$_POST['File'];
        $model->nama_file = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'nama_file');
        if($model->save()){
            $simpan->saveAs(Yii::app()->basePath .
                '/../files/' . $model->nama_file.'');
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id_file));
        }
        }
    }

    $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

2. view.php under /protected/views/file/view.php

   ```
    <?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbDetailView',array(
          'data'=>$model,
          'attributes'=>array(
                         'id_file',
                         'nama_file',
                         'deskripsi',
                         'id_user',
                         'id_kategori',
                         'tgl_post',
                                 ),
    )); ?>
   ```

How to do that? Please help me, thanks for answering me.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a request to the controller/action on link click like this .
For example:
**// this is just a sample code .Please change it to suit you**

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.TbDetailView', array(
    'data'=>$model,
    'attributes'=>array(
        'title',             // title attribute (in plain text)
        'owner.name',        // an attribute of the related object "owner"
        'description:html',  // description attribute in HTML
        array(               // related city displayed as a link
            'label'=>'City',
            'type'=>'raw',
            'value'=>CHtml::link(CHtml::encode($model->city->name),
                                 array('city/view','id'=>$model->city->id)),
        ),
    ),
));
```

and add the following code there :
**// this is just a sample code .Please change it  to suit you**

```
$length = filesize($yourfile) 
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Length: $length");
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=sth.pdf");
```

Comment: hey thanks, I have successfully show it. But, where I put the code:
`$length = filesize($yourfile) `
`header("Content-type: application/pdf");`
`header("Content-Length: $length");`
`header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=sth.pdf");`

Comment: create action inside your controller and paste it there